# JQM 1.4.2 collapsible event expand dont work

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

We generate a collapsible content dynamically like this:

```
$('#'+object.TARGET).html(response).trigger('create');
```

The collapsible work very well

```
<div data-role="collapsible" id="ims-page-start-content-detail-vertrag">
    <h2>Mieter</h2>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

but if we want to use the expand-event with:

```
$("#ims-page-start-content-detail-vertrag").on( "collapsibleexpand", function( event, ui ) { alert("test"); } );
```

or

```
$("#ims-page-start-content-detail-vertrag").collapsible({
    expand: function( event, ui ) { alert("test"); }
});
```

there is no answere! what we do wrong? Tanks a lot ;-)

---

we add this:

```
$(document).off('pageshow','#ims-page-start').on('pageshow','#ims-page-start',function(){

$('#ims-page-start-content-detail-vertrag').bind('expand', function () {    alert('Expanded');
   }).bind('collapse', function () {
   alert('Collapsed');
    });

});
```

but this still not working!
we think the problem is how to generate the collapible dynamically

Comment: it depends on how you append them dynamically.

Answer (score 5):

You have two solutions to listen `collapsibecollapse` and `collpsibleexpand` events on *dynamically* created collapsibles.

1. The first and straight-forward one is to *delegate* event.

   ```
   $(document).on("collapsibleexpand collapsiblecollapse", "[data-role=collapsible]", function (e) {
     /* do something */
   });
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/xEY64/)**
2. The second solution is to *bind* event while you are creating them *dynamically*.

   ```
   $(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () {
     $("parentDiv")
       .append($('<div data-role="collapsible"><h3>Dynamic</h3><p>Content</p></div>')
       .collapsible({
       expand: function () {
           /* Expanded - do something */
       },
       collapse: function () {
           /* Collapsed - do something */
       }
     }));
   });
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/qfSzu/)**